# webpack5 html templates with partials not working with "npm run dev"

Tags: webpack

In order to prepare click dummies I'd like to use `html` templates that webpack offers via the `HtmlWebpackPlugin`. The html templates look like this:

// src/templates/index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
[...]
<body>
    <h1 class="text-red-600">Test: include HTML partial with standard lodash functionality</h1>
    <%= require('./partials/header').default %>
</body>
</html>
```

// src/templates/partials/header.html

```html
<h2>Header in H2 as Test</h2>
```

and the significant webpack config:

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
 module {
  rules: [
   {
    test: /\.html$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: ['html-loader']
   }
  ]
 },
 plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
   filename: 'index.html',
   template: './src/templates/index.html',
  })
 ]
}
```

Whenever I run

```js
npm run dev
```

this error is thrown:

```html
Cannot Get /
```

which suggests that the template is not rendered at the correct path. However, the templates are compiled correctly when running

```js
npm run build
```

So the error only happens when during development. However, I fail to find the source of the culprit.

I prepared a [github repo](https://github.com/rowild/webpack5-boilerplate/tree/main) and also forked it to [codesandbox](https://github.com/rowild/webpack5-boilerplate/tree/main).

Can anybody help me find out what is wrong?

PS: I have a `pug` setup working just fine. Unfortunately the `pug-loader` is not maintained anymore. Furthermore, it only supports pug v2, which is not recommended anymore due to its dependency on core-js v2, which has serious security flaws. And `pug-plain-loader` cannot parse the HtmlWebpackPlugin's `options` object.

Answer (score 0):

This is, in my opinion, not stated clearly enough in the docu nor in the examples. If using html template, there MUST NOT be a test for html in the webpack config!

Then, when a html file loads a partial, the `html-loader` is "plugged into" the require statement like this:

```html
<%= require('html-loader!./partials/header.html').default %>
```

Then it works.
Unfortunately without hot reloading, though...